# HtmlDocument does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I cant seem to understand why this wont work.  I keep getting an error that says `HtmlDocument` does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//Create the Browser Window
BrowserWindow broWin = new BrowserWindow();
broWin.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.Name] = "Execute Automation";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(broWin);
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't have a constructor with one argument.  Where do you see otherwise in the documentation?

Comment: HtmlDocument has no constructor, you can't create an instance of it by yourself.

Comment: the error is telling you what the issue is .. look at the msdn documentation and understand what arguments it takes `1 , 2 or none` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx this is pretty straight forward. it takes zero arguments meaning has no constructor

Comment: I thought so as well but in the tutorial I am watching he passes broWin in the parameters but when I do that it gives me an error. @MethodMan

Comment: Which tutorial? Are you by any chance combining CodedUI and HtmlAgilityPack or Awesonium?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4FVGcVqI7w&list=PL6tu16kXT9PrBqNFlv5sk6-63Br-Clmyd&index=10#t=8.2435075

Answer (score 1):

You should use the HtmlDocument(UITestControl) constructor from namespace `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.htmldocument.aspx